# GOLANG: Learning goroutine took me to a deadlock

Tags: go, deadlock, goroutine

I'm a GO newbie and I'm trying to figure out how does goroutines work and how to synchronize them.
This is a simple program I wrote to learn something about them:

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "sync"
        "time"
)

func printAfterDelay(delay time.Duration, message string, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
        time.Sleep(delay)
        fmt.Println(message)
        wg.Done()
}

func add(a int, b int, chan1 chan int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
        c := a + b
        chan1 <- c
        //close(chan1)
        wg.Done()
}

func printer(chan1 chan int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
        for result := range chan1 {
                //result := <-chan1
                //time.Sleep(2000 * time.Millisecond)
                fmt.Println(result)
        }
        close(chan1)
        wg.Done()
}

func main() {
        //var wg sync.WaitGroup
        wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}

        fmt.Println("Start...")

        wg.Add(1)
        go printAfterDelay(2000*time.Millisecond, "Try", wg)

        chan1 := make(chan int)
        wg.Add(1)
        go add(5, 4, chan1, wg)

        wg.Add(1)
        go add(3, 1, chan1, wg)

        wg.Add(1)
        go printer(chan1, wg)

        //time.Sleep(3000 * time.Millisecond)
        wg.Wait()

        fmt.Println("End")
}
```

The add function takes two int, sums them and pass the result to a chan.
The printer function takes the results from the chan and print them.
The two funtions are called in main() as goroutines, so i also passed a WaitGroup as a pointer, that is incremented before calling the goroutines and decremented when the functions end.

Anyway when I execute the compiled program it prints:

```
Start...
9
4
Try
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!
goroutine 16 [semacquire]:
sync.runtime_Semacquire(0x18334008)
  /usr/lib/go/src/pkg/runtime/sema.goc:199 +0x37
sync.(*WaitGroup).Wait(0x183240e0)
  /usr/lib/go/src/pkg/sync/waitgroup.go:129 +0x12d
main.main()        
  /home/ettore/go/src/example/goroutine/main.go:52 +0x1e5

goroutine 19 [finalizer wait]:
runtime.park(0x80599e0, 0x814f000, 0x814e3e9)
  /usr/lib/go/src/pkg/runtime/proc.c:1369 +0x94
runtime.parkunlock(0x814f000, 0x814e3e9)       
  /usr/lib/go/src/pkg/runtime/proc.c:1385 +0x3
frunfinq()        
  /usr/lib/go/src/pkg/runtime/mgc0.c:2644 +0xc5
runtime.goexit()        
  /usr/lib/go/src/pkg/runtime/proc.c:1445

goroutine 23 [chan receive]:
main.printer(0x1831a090, 0x183240e0)        
  /home/ettore/go/src/example/goroutine/main.go:23 +0x46
created by main.main        
  /home/ettore/go/src/example/goroutine/main.go:49 +0x1d7
```

Where and what is the problem(s)?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to read the documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works. By that I mean that it doesn't deadlock. 
Since you have the printer function in a range loop over the channel, it'll automatically stop after the channel is closed. I added the 3 sec delay near the end to give the try loop time to print. [Read the documentation though. It'll explain 100% of these details.](http://tour.golang.org/welcome/1)

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "sync"
        "time"
)

func printAfterDelay(delay time.Duration, message string, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
        time.Sleep(delay)
        fmt.Println(message)

}

func add(a int, b int, chan1 chan int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
        c := a + b
        chan1 <- c
        wg.Done()
}

func printer(chan1 chan int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
        for result := range chan1 {
                fmt.Println(result)
        }
}

func main() {
        //var wg sync.WaitGroup
        wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}

        fmt.Println("Start...")

        go printAfterDelay(2000*time.Millisecond, "Try", wg)

        chan1 := make(chan int)
        wg.Add(1)
        go add(5, 4, chan1, wg)

        wg.Add(1)
        go add(3, 1, chan1, wg)

        go printer(chan1, wg)

        time.Sleep(3000 * time.Millisecond)
        wg.Wait()
    close(chan1)

        fmt.Println("End")
}
```

Comment: By the way, you could remove the waitgroup altogether since the printer function will "freeze" and wait until either there is some value in the channel to read or it is closed.

Comment: No, you do need the waitgroup (or equivalent). Otherwise there's no guarantee that the sending functions will compete before you close the channel and you will get a panic. Never use a sleep for synchronization.